# Laplace transform of simple function

Tags: laplace-transform

I have the function below:

$$3-2t+3t^2$$

I tried to get the transfer function, but my solution seems to be wrong, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong:

$$\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s^3}$$

Comment: Are we just finding $\int_0^\infty (3-2t+3t^2)e^{-st}\,dt$? If so (using integration by parts for the last two terms) I think we get $\frac{3}{s}-\frac{2}{s^2}+\frac{6}{s^3}$.  As to what you did wrong, that is hard to know if one does not see what you did.

Comment: You can use the following properties: $ \mathcal{L} \{1\} =\frac{1}{s}$ , $\mathcal{L} \{t^n \} =\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$

Comment: It would be better if you added what was done in a clear way. Indeed, Andre got what you are looking for.

Comment: Is the function of $t$ meant to be the impulse response?

Comment: Thanks guys, this was so simple I was ashamed to continue the question :( got it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at a table and seeing how $$\mathcal L\{1\}=\frac{1}{s},\quad \mathcal L\{t\}=\frac{1}{s^2},\quad \mathcal L\{t^2\}=\frac{2}{s^3}$$... add them up, combine the constants, hope to get something like $$F(s)=\frac{3}{s}-\frac{2}{s^2}+\frac{6}{s^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}f(t)&=3-2t+3t^2\\
\\
F(s)&=\mathcal L\{3-2t+3t^2\}\\
\\
&=\mathcal L\{3\}-\mathcal L\{2t\}+\mathcal L\{3t^2\}\\
\\
&=3\mathcal L\{t^0\}-2\mathcal L\{t^1\}+3\mathcal L\{t^2\}\\\\&=\end{align*}$$

use
$$\boxed{\begin{align*}\mathcal L\{t^n\}&=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{s^{n+1}},\qquad n>-1\\&=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}},\qquad \qquad n\in\mathbb Z> 0\qquad\end{align*}}$$